# Two routers same network cant see devices

Tags: router, lan

Two routers same network.

I can't see devices when I am connected to the other router.
Dhcp is disabled on both.
Both have different WAN IPs

Router LAN IPs are in the same subnet.

I have a DHCP server for IPs. I have one router for OpenVPN (Cisco RV260) Another router for Internet (Cisco RV325) Gateway to gateway VPN to my office with the RV325 to another RV325. If I can get the 260 to get site to site to work with the RV325 this is moot, but still would like to know why or how o get this to work. Or why it isn't working... seen by both..

How can I fix so if either router is used everything is seen on the network?

Comment: Dhcp is disabled on both.   ..........   Where is your DHCP server?

Comment: Quite a lot is unclear. Please add to your question:  DHCP is disabled on both routers. How do device get their IP address (static?), default gateway and nameserver? What kind of routers? SOHO-NATting routers? Routers that support HSRP? What do you mean by "everything is seen on the network"?

Comment: There is only one router per network by definition. Probably you have to use a repeater or switch. Please tell us what you want to do.

Comment: @zomega *"There is only one router per network by definition"* that is not really true.

Comment: I have a DHCP server for IPs. 

I have one router for OpenVPN (Cisco RV260)
Another router for Internet (Cisco RV325)

Gateway to gateway VPN to my office with the RV325 to another RV325.
If I can get the 260 to get site to site to work with the RV325 this is moot, but still would like to know why or how o get this to work. Or why it isn't working... seen by both..

Comment: Please don't respond to clarification or additional info -requests on comments. Better way is to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1767973/edit) your question to add new info there (as I now did for you), so it's readily available. I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how SE sites work.